# Parse js table from the file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I write a programe in JavaScript where I want to add file "tables.js". There are many tables saved in this file.I want to validate the data in each table.
 How can I save each of these tables as a separate variable? var people = ...; var city = ...

Part of tables.js file below.

```
{
 people:  [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Asdfg'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Carl',
    lastName: 'Qwerty'
}],
city:  [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Prague',
    size: 'M',
    continent:'Europe'
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'London',
    size: 'XL',
    continent:'Europe'
}]
}
```

I have tried `JSON.parse` so far but unfortunately I can't split this file into separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is extract from  the object Keys and allocate them to new variables

There are two ways of doing this . One is dot Notations as per the example  and the other is bracket notation which looks like this

> let people = data['people'];
>
> let city= data['city'];

```js
var data = {
 people:  [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Asdfg'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Carl',
    lastName: 'Qwerty'
}],
city:  [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Prague',
    size: 'M',
    continent:'Europe'
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'London',
    size: 'XL',
    continent:'Europe'
}]
};

let people = data.people;
let city = data.city;

console.log(people)
console.log('=================')
console.log(city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as above but with ES6 (latest JS version) constants and deconstruct features.

```js
const data = {
  people: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Asdfg'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Carl',
    lastName: 'Qwerty'
  }],
  city: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Prague',
    size: 'M',
    continent: 'Europe'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'London',
    size: 'XL',
    continent: 'Europe'
  }]
}

const {people, city} = data

console.log('People:', people)
console.log('City:', city)
```